# Перебрать элементы Deque/Queue

Tags: java, очередь

Привет всем! Как можно перебрать все элементы Deque и Queue как в массиве?

Comment: А зачем это нужно?

Comment: А в чем проблема то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Queue<Integer> q = new ArrayDeque<>(Arrays.asList(11, 33, 55, 22, 44));

//#1 for-each
q.forEach(System.out::println);

//#2 итерация "как в массиве" с i
Iterator<Integer> iterator = q.iterator();
for (int i = 0; ; ++i) {
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Integer value = iterator.next();
        System.out.println(i + " " + value);
    } else break;
}

//#3 итерация "как в настоящем массиве"
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>(q);
for (int i = 0, max = integers.size(); i < max; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + " " + integers.get(i));
}
```

Результат:

```
11
33
55
22
44
0 11
1 33
2 55
3 22
4 44
```

Answer (score 3):

Интерфейсы `Queue` и `Deque` расширяют интерфейс `Collection`, поэтому перебрать все элементы можно как и в любой коллекции - с помощью расширенного цикла `for`:

```
void enumerateQueue(Queue<T> queue) {
    for(T t : queue) {
        // здесь можно делать что угодно с очередным элементом коллекции
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

Как и любая коллекция, `Queue` и `Deque` имеют метод `stream()`, который позволяет перебрать элементы с использованием Stream API:

```
void queueAsStream(Queue<T> queue) {
    queue.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```